# Drupal 7 - Node Clone Alternatives

Tags: 7

just want to ask if there are any other suggested alternatives for cloning a node for drupal 7. Now I know most of you will answer "[Node Clone](http://drupal.org/project/node_clone) Module", but is there any other module out there that can do the same thing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"Drupal way" is to collaborate, not compete. It means that anyone wanting to write his own cloning solution will be asked to cooperate with author of existing one to provide what he finds lacking. Only if that's not possible, and some basic differences in approach or expected results are found, community will welcome new module. Otherwise it'll just die silently, unloved.

That said, you can use node exporting and importing tools to export nodes, edit them or not and import again, possibly under new `nid`. [Node export](http://drupal.org/project/node_export) is example of modules that can do that. Probably there are other ways to get content duplicated, and if you can think of basically different scenario, there is a big chance someone got that implemented.